# I'm trying to add text and images on my website but whenever I put them in they go into my header or just the top

Tags: html

I'm sure it has something to do with the nav section but I'm not sure. the random stuff is just a placement for what is in there originally so you can ignore that. on another page of mine it does the same thing where my code goes into the header instead of below it, I copied the same header onto that page as well.  I have tried moving the image and text to above the nav but that didn't change anything.

thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <img class="first"src="./images/random.jpg" alt="">
    
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <h4></h4>
            </div> 
            <ul class="nav-links">
            </li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html">
random</a</li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random<li>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    
    </section>
    <section class="classes">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="About">
            <h5>random text</h5>
            <img src="./images/random.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is all over the place. If you're just using notepad or notepad++ I'd suggest getting VSCode and a HTML Formatting extension. Make sure your images are in the correct folder and you're pointed towards the correct path. Read through your code and make sure you don't have unnecessary tags there.

Comment: I am using VSCode, any change you know how the code should look?.

Comment: @GamesVideo Make sure non-void elements have both an opening and a closing tag. Indentation (e.g. one tab per depth) is helpful to see such syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is off.  check it in w3 html validator [link here](https://validator.w3.org/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <img class="first"src="./images/random.jpg" alt="">
    
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <h4></h4>
            </div> 
            <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html">
random</a></li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
                <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random<li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        
    <section class="classes">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="About">
            <h5>random text</h5>
            <img src="http://placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        
        </div>
        </section>
   
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the image `<img class="first"src="./images/random.jpg" alt="">` comes first in your body. As there is no styling, it is normal it comes at the head of your page.

In addition images are inline elements. You should put them in a block element like a paragraph.

Comment: The <img class="first"src="./images/random.jpg" alt=""> is fine its the second image that I'm struggling with it being in the first image.

Comment: have you tried to put <p> around your image ? usually it's not recommanded to have a "block" element like h5 followed by an "inline" element like a picture.
'<h5>random text</h5>
<p><img src="http://placeholder.com/150" alt=""></p>'

Comment: I just tried using <p> on the image but it didn't work the image is still overlaid on the first image.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
    
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4></h4>
    </div> 
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html">
random</a</li>
      <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
      <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
      <li> <a class="nav-links" href="./random.html"></a>random</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

<section class="classes">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="About">
      <h5>random text</h5>
      <img src="./images/random.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).